# The property "ApplicationId" was not found in type "ParameterEditor"

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I am having a problem with a user control I've built with Silverlight. The problem is that in the user control's class I added a property `public Guid ApplicationId` and on a page I want to bind to some value. When I try to do this I get the "The property 'ApplicationId' was not found in type 'ParameterEditor'" where `ParameterEditor` is my user control.

Some code for the problem. In the user control:

```
    public ParameterEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetParametersForEdit();
    }

    public Guid ApplicationId
    {
        get { return (Guid)GetValue(ApplicationGUID); }
        set
        {
            if (ApplicationId == value) return;
            SetValue(ApplicationGUID, value);
        }
    }
```

And in the XAML of the page I want to display this control I have this:

```
<vbView:ParameterEditor x:Name="paramConfig" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"
                       DataContext="{Binding SelectedRoute}"
                       ApplicationId="{Binding ApplicationId}"
                        />
```

And the `ApplicationId` is in the page's .cs file. Problem is I've done this thing with other controls and it works fine, I honestly can't tell why this is happening here.

---

`DependencyProperty` definition:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ApplicationGUID = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Application GUID", typeof(Guid), typeof(ParameterEditor),
        new PropertyMetadata((source, _) => ((ParameterEditor)source).SetInitialGuid()));

    private void SetInitialGuid()
    {
        ApplicationId = Guid.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: How is your DependencyProperty `ApplicationGUID` defined?

Comment: I have updated the question with the definition. But does the `DependencyProperty` matter in that it cannot find my property on the page?